# iteration of a control to retrieve its children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am adding toolbox-items on a toolbox where it is embedded into an expander control on xaml. how can I iterate and traverse among those toolbox-items? my assumption is that toolbox are children to toolbox or should I go through expander?

Thanks.

XAML goes here:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0">                    
            <Label Name="lblFind">Find:</Label>
        <StackPanel Name="spFind" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Name="txtFind" Width="200" Height="22" ></TextBox>

        <Button Content="Go" Width="60" Height="30"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txtFind, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        **<Expander x:Name="expander_Controls" Header="Controls" Content="{StaticResource myRESOURCE}" IsExpanded="True" />**


    </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    <!-- GridSplitter -->
    <GridSplitter Focusable="False" Width="2" Background="LightGray"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>


    <StackPanel Grid.Column="5" Background="AliceBlue">
        <ListView Background="LightGray" Opacity="1" ForceCursor="False" x:Name="myTree" x:FieldModifier="public">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Nodes" Width="80"/>
                 </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

solution:

```
var myList = this.FindResource("MyResource") as Toolbox;

for (int i = 0; i <= (myList .Items.Count - 1); i++)
{
    Object objResult = myList.GetType().GetProperty("Tag").GetValue(myList.Items[i], null);
    MessageBox.Show(objList.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: can you post your xaml code?  don't quite understand

Comment: Please see above. I updated it. You will see an <Expander> in there.

Comment: can you also post the code defining your resource "myRESOURCE", how are you adding the toolbox items?

Comment: Thank you so much. I just wrote it and works fine. (above)